# How to find if the selected point is on land or water?

Tags: r, netcdf

Using the function locator in R, i can press a point in the map of the netcdf4 file and it gives me their coordinates. However, I also want that it displays if the point is on land or water. That information is on the variable mask_rho, but given a pressed coordinate, I do not know how to extract it.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(fields)

nc_file <- 'C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Proyecto/ich/input/newperush_avg.Y2011.M12.newperush.nc'
lon <- 280.81572993
lat <- -8.148526246

nc       <- nc_open(nc_file)
lon_rho  <- ncvar_get(nc, 'lon_rho')
lat_rho  <- ncvar_get(nc, 'lat_rho')
mask_rho <- ncvar_get(nc, 'mask_rho')

xlim <- c(lon-1.5 , lon+1.5)
ylim <- c(lat-1.5 , lat+1.5)

X11()
image.plot(lon_rho,lat_rho,mask_rho, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, xlab = 
'LON', ylab = 'LAT')
points(lon,lat)

locator(n = 1, type = 'p')
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `sp::point.in.polygon`, assuming that you have polygons of land or water.